# How can I "reset" an array's keys?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array and I delete certain elements, I end up with an array that has non-consecutive keys:

```js
var arr = [15,16,20,21,-1];
delete arr[1];
delete arr[3];
console.log(arr);
// [0: 15, 2: 20, 4: -1]
```

How can I "reset" the array's keys?

I should end up with an array like so:

```
[0: 15, 1: 20, 2: -1]
```

Comment: Is this a **valid** _array_?

Comment: This does not look like an array, and the requirement are unclear.

Comment: I was describing an array, yes.  Sorry if the way I output it confused my meaning!

Comment: Just don't use the first answer on that duplicate, extending native objects is an extremely bad thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, you can use `Array.prototype.filter` method.

```
var array = [];
array[30] = 1;
array.length; // 31

var compactArray = array.filter(function (item) {
    return item !== undefined;
});

compactArray.length; // 1
```

If it's an object, `for..in` loop will be usefull

```
var array = { 31: 1};
var compactArray = [];
for (var i in array) {
    compactArray.push(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, array.filter seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop throw array and if its a valid item, then push in another array.

Also, when you do something like this,

```
var arr = [];
arr[3] = 15;
```

`arr` is actually `[null, null, null, 15]`

Following is an example.

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [];
  var result = [];

  arr[3] = 15;
  arr[7] = 20;
  arr[19] = -1;

  console.log(arr);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  })

  console.log(result);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean your **object** is like this

```
var obj = {3: 15, 7: 20, 19: -1};
var output = {};
var counter = 0;
for ( var id in obj )
{
   output[ String( counter ) ] = obj[ id ];
   counter++;
}
console.log( output );
```